# How to ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG from dynamically generated script for all databases on a server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, alter, catalog

How can I alter full text catalog by its Database.Owner.Name full catalog name?

```
declare @db_name sysname;
declare db cursor for 
select name from sys.Databases where name like 'myprefix%'
open db
fetch next from db into @db_name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @sql = 'ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [' +  @db_name + '].dbo.IndexedContent REBUILD'
  exec sp_executesql @sql   
  fetch next from db into @db_name
end
close db;
deallocate db;
```

But SQL Server complains about

```
Incorrect syntax near '.'
```

The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176095.aspx does not explicitly specify if catalog_name can be fully qualified.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx) says that the catalog name is a single element i.e. no schema or database prefix (unlike the syntax for [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), for example). Therefore you probably need to switch execution context to the correct database first:

```
set @sql = 'USE ' +  QUOTENAME(@db_name) + '; ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG IndexedContent REBUILD;'
```